# boto3 lambda api gateway : trigger point gets updated only if i unselect and select "Use Lambda Proxy integration" manually

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Using python boto3 I am trying to create a trigger point for my lambda function. Resource creation, put_method, put_integration take place properly. But under lambda function->configuration->triggers, I do not see API Gateway created, also if I try to test the API Gateway it throws "Internal Error". But, if I go to API Gateway->my_rest_api->resouurce->method->Integration Request, here based on the configuration that I provided "*Use Lambda Proxy integration*" will be selected, if I deselect, and revert back i.e select. The function behaves as expected.
I am trying to automate AWS using boto3, this is hindering the process. Below is the function:

```
def add_method_integration(self, rest_api_id, resource_id, http_method, status_code, request_parameters, type,integration_http_method, uri, authorization_type="None"):
    
    request_parameters = self.helper.generate_method_query_string(request_parameters)
    print(request_parameters)
    put_method = self.gateway_client.put_method(
        restApiId=rest_api_id,
        resourceId=resource_id,
        httpMethod=http_method,
        authorizationType=authorization_type,
        requestParameters=request_parameters
    )
    print(put_method)
    if not isinstance(status_code, list):
        put_method_response = self.gateway_client.put_method_response(
            restApiId=rest_api_id,
            resourceId=resource_id,
            httpMethod=http_method,
            statusCode=status_code
        )
        print(put_method_response)
    else:
        for status_code in status_code:
            put_method_response = self.gateway_client.put_method_response(
                restApiId=rest_api_id,
                resourceId=resource_id,
                httpMethod=http_method,
                statusCode=status_code
            )
            print(put_method_response)

    uri = f"arn:aws:apigateway:{self.gateway_client.meta.region_name}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/{uri}/invocations"
    put_integration = self.gateway_client.put_integration(
        restApiId=rest_api_id,
        resourceId=resource_id,
        httpMethod=http_method,
        type=type,
        integrationHttpMethod=integration_http_method,
        uri=uri
    )
    print(put_integration)`
```

what am I missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [add_permission](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.add_permission) to your function, so that your api gateway is allowed to invoke it. Example values for such permissions are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-permissions).

Comment: "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole" - role is added to the function

Comment: @NehaS These permissions are different then your execution policy. You need to add [resource-based policie](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html) to your function, not [execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html). These are two different things.